# The method add(GObject) in the type GraphicsProgram is not applicable for the arguments (GRectangle)

Tags: java

Going through the Stanford CS106A course in Java, building "breakout" as a GraphicsProgram, and am hung up on adding the paddle. I have (in the declarations)

```
private GRectangle paddle;
```

And this method to add it to the screen

```
private void createPaddle(){
    paddle = new GRectangle(10,10,PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
    double paddleWidth = paddle.getWidth();
    double paddleX = getWidth()/2 - paddleWidth;
    double paddleY = getHeight() - PADDLE_Y_OFFSET;
    paddle.setLocation(paddleX, paddleY);
    paddle.setLocation((getWidth()/2-paddleWidth),(getHeight() - PADDLE_Y_OFFSET));
    add(paddle);
}
```

All of the variables used there are declared, but I get the error "The method add(GObject) in the type GraphicsProgram is not applicable for the arguments (GRectangle)." There's an add() method in the [GRectangle documentation](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/javataskforce/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GRectangle.html#GRectangle()), but it appears that this exists to add a point to the rectangle (I'm not sure what that means).

How would I add the rectangle to the canvas?

Comment: After looking in the documentation maybe you should use [GRect](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/javataskforce/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GRect.html) cause the GRectangle isn't inherit from [GObject](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/complete/acm/graphics/GObject.html) which is needed by the `add(paddle);` method.

Comment: Ah, you're right. GRect not GRectangle. Thanks!